# How can I "Replace" Exception with my own code?

Tags: vb.net, exception

I would like to use my own catch-exception when exceptions occours.

My test code is like this...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder
            sb.Append("test")

        Catch ex As Exception
            ex.Alert("Yo")

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class


<Serializable>
Public Class Exception
    Inherits System.Exception

    Public Sub Alert(text As String)
        MsgBox(text)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(message As String)
        MyBase.New(message)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(message As String, innerException As Exception)
        MyBase.New(message, innerException)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub New(serializationInfo As Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, streamingContext As Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)
    End Sub

End Class
```

But it doesn't catch the error.

How can I replace the "Exception" class with my own class?

Answer (score 2):

You've successfully created a custom exception type (though just calling it `Exception` is likely to lead to confusion, you should give it a more specific name).  But nothing is *throwing* your exception type.  None of the built-in .NET code was built with *your custom exception* in mind, so nothing is going to throw that type.

*Your* code can throw your custom exception type.  For example, throwing an exception based on some condition:

```
Try
    If someCondition Then
        Throw New Exception()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    ex.Alert("Yo")
End Try
```

Generally something like this would happen deeper in the call stack, such as in a method you've called and not on the same level as the `Try/Catch` here.  (Consider the general advice that one should not use exceptions for control flow, which is kind of what's happening in this contrived example.)

But the point is that *your code* would throw your custom exception, built-in .NET code certainly wouldn't do that.

---

As an aside, coupling your exception type with `MsgBox` effectively couples it with a specific UI technology.  That may be fine for your needs, but it's mixing concerns that generally shouldn't be mixed.  An exception itself should really just carry information about the problem, the exception *handling* logic should handle displaying that information, or logging it, or in any way responding to the problem.

Currently this custom exception type doesn't add anything to the information about the problem, it *only* couples itself to the UI.  So when you consider its usage... All it does is replace `MsgBox` but does so only in places where you are also able to use `MsgBox`, so it effectively gains you nothing.  In the long run you may be starting off in the wrong direction in terms of effective exception handling.